# Getting the name of a referenced function?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a little work on one of my open source projects and could use some other brains on a problem. Basically, I'm trying to find a more efficient way to get the full reference name to a function.

https://github.com/geuis/argon/issues/2

Basically Argon serializes and deserializes native data types in javascript. It has support for storing application functions but not native functions.

When you serialize a native function, you get something like

```
function apply() { [native code] }
```

So ideally, I'll parse the string and detect "[native code]" but the issue is the function name.

In Argon's syntax, you would do something like this:

```
argon.local.set('key', window.Array.apply);
```

But the problem is you only get the function's name and I would need to determine the 'window.Array' part.

I've looked at Function.name and Function.caller but they don't help.

The only workable idea we've had so far is to recurse from the root window object over every node until there's a match. This will work, but I want to exhaust any other ideas first.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it. Functions don't have a reference back to the prototype that uses them. And the same function could be used in several prototypes, so which one would be returned by the hypothetical mechanism you want?

Comment: Both `Array.prototype.indexOf` and `String.prototype.indexOf` just print as `function indexOf() { [ native code ] }`. There's no way to tell which is which when you serialize it.

Comment: @Barmar - there is a way to tell them apart of course... you can compare the value (not the string representation) to each of the functions. The question really is, why even try so hard? what's the use case here?

Comment: @Amit I think the question makes it pretty clear: he's trying to serialize objects that can include references to functions.

Comment: @Barmar - yes you're right, just feels extremely XY-ish ;-)

Comment: Unless there's a really strong use case here (I can't see it), I'd avoid this altogether. Make it very clear in your documentation that it's not supported, throw an error when you encounter such values, and you're good to go.

Comment: I have an idea, what if you get your input like this (String path instead of the real refrence): `argon.local.set('key', 'window.Array.apply');` ... Now in the `set` function you can split the input by dots and access it like this: `window['window']['Array']['apply']` so now you have both the path and the real reference, it will work for something like `document.body.click` as well like this: `window['document']['body']['click']`

Comment: @Night2 yeah I already considered that. Problem is it breaks the interface pattern where you don't have to specify the data type.

Comment: @Geuis: I guess if you create a list of all test-cases that Argon must be able to store and retrieve is better. You might end-up re constructing the structure but at the end it will work for anything hopefully. I think keeping the current functionality for normal data types and arrays is good while you can have a setObject function for objects. I just did a test and created a new object from a class and tried to store it using Argon and get it back but it didn't work too and returned to me undefined. I will post the sample code in next comment.

Comment: If I have a class like this: `function obj_test(){this.x = 1;}` and I use Argon like this: `argon.local.set('a', new obj_test());` I will get `undefined` when I try to get 'a' with Argon. So your problem isn't only the references but also storing the created objects as well.

Comment: @Night2 Thanks for finding that use case. I'm going to create an issue and take a look at it.